# a unique combination of fql and graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

am trying to search the fb posts of a given keyword but need only results with condition of having more than a specific comments count or likes count, i mean the results will only have posts which have a minimum of given value in comments count and likes count.

i tried with many developers but all are saying that its not possible, as the graph api don't offer this kind of method or http call functions.

but what my point is, there will be a possible way to mix both fql and graph and get the results, something like this, but i don't know the exact schema to use.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON
  &query=select comments from comment where object_id in 
    (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/')
  &pretty=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mix Graph API and FQL requests in a single call using [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). You have to use the new Graph API url instead of the REST API url you show in your question. You will also need an `access_token` to get this data.

Facebook does have a `comments.count` and a `likes` object for the `comment` FQL table. That give a numerical comment count you can query against:

```
SELECT comments, likes FROM comment WHERE object_id IN 
  (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/')
  AND (comments.count > 5 OR likes > 5)
```